# AngularJS, Chinese food, names and number inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, forms

Alright, I'm building fake Chinese food menu using AngularJS and jquery.  The first section simply lists items, the second section allows the user to "order" food, then creates a total price by multiplying the food ordered (checkboxes) by the quantity (number input).

The problem is, I can't seem to get the value of the number input through its name.

Here, I believe, is all the relevant code:

```
    <div id = "order">
<hr>
<h2> Order </h2>
<form>
 <!--  So I need to somehow extra the price of the item, and the number in the 'number' input, multiply
  them, and then add the resulting number to a "total" variable.  Hmmm -->
  <h3 class = "orderSec">Main</h3>
  <div ng-repeat = "x in main"><input type = "number" min = "0" max = "10" name = {{x.food}}></input> {{x.food}} ({{x.price | currency}})<input type = "checkbox" value = {{x.price}} id = {{x.food}}></input></div>
  <br>
  Total: <span id = "total"></span>
  <br>
  <input type = "submit" onClick = "total()">
  </form>
</div>
```

And...

```
function total()
{
  //this needs to gather the price (value) of all checked boxes, then multiply it by the value of adjacent number input
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if (this.checked)
      {
        console.log($(this).val());
        var quantityId = this.id;
        console.log(quantityId);
        var money = $('input[name=quantityId]').val();
        console.log(money);
        //why doesn't the above give me the number in the input?


        var money2 = document.getElementsByName(quantityId).value;
        console.log(money2);
        //the above also comes back "undefined.""  WTF!?
      }
  }
);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several issues in your code:

- You need to hook event handlers to the checkboxes to run your code when they are checked/unchecked, not only on load of the page
- The same is true for the quantity fields
- You need to calculate the total under those events, not when the submit button is clicked, as the form will be submit at that point and the total will not be seen
- You need to concatenate the `quantityId` value to the selector string, not use it as a literal value
- You need to select the elements related to the checked boxes, not select all of them by name

That being said, you should note that the logic can be made made much simpler using a single function which calculates the total when either a box is checked or a quantity changed. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $checkboxes = $('form :checkbox').on('change', calcTotal);
  let $quantities = $('form .quantity').on('input', calcTotal);
  
  function calcTotal() {
    let total = 0;
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
      let $checkbox = $(this);
      total += parseFloat($checkbox.val()) * parseInt($checkbox.siblings('input.quantity').val(), 10);
    });    
    $('#total').text(total);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="order">
  <hr>
  <h2> Order </h2>
  <form>
    <h3 class="orderSec">Main</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="x in main">
      <input type="number" min="0" max="10" value="0" name="Lorem" class="quantity" />
      Lorem (9.99)
      <input type="checkbox" value="9.99" id="Lorem" />
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="x in main">
      <input type="number" min="0" max="10" value="0" name="Ipsum" class="quantity" />
      Ipsum (5.99)
      <input type="checkbox" value="5.99" id="Ipsum" />
    </div><br /> 
    Total: <span id="total"></span><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```